# Twilio delay of 2 seconds when calling within Australia

Tags: twilio

We use Twilio as our VOIP provider but there is a ~2 second audio delay on every phone call, making the service unusable. This happens for both landlines and mobiles. Before we drop the service is there anyone else who has experienced this or even better found a solution?

Comment: could this possibly be something due to your implementation, network or perhaps infrastructure? we are making calls from South Africa to Australia using Twilio without the issues you are describing.

for some of our tests we were using Twilio to call while we had a Skype video call active as well, so that we could see how the "experience" would be, and we again had no issues with this and actually we were impressed that the latency on each communication channel was in fact the same.

Comment: I submitted a help request and they said there was lag because the path was Aus -> us -> Aus. It's possible they've since set up local servers.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that is good to know for future reference.

Comment: @LouisLewis and Richard, do any of you have an update regarding this? It still seems to be happening... =(

Comment: @BardiHarborow no. Twilio is still unusable aus <-> aus

Answer (score 1):

I just got an email from Plivo support regarding this:

> Recently Plivo has added a new point of presence (PoP) in Sydney, Australia that connects directly with a local Tier 1 carrier in Australia. This means that all of our customers automatically have access to latency free (sub 20ms connectivity) voice calls within Australia and New Zealand.
>   For more information on this refer the link provided below https://www.plivo.com/blog/announcing-new-australian-pop/
>
> If you are facing any delay/latency with conference/Call kindly revert to us with Call UUID. We will look into it and investigate.

The post linked was posted on the 25 Feb 2015.